# why `stack` cannot work on the result of `tapply`?

Tags: r, stack, tapply

Assuming I have a data frame `df`

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(x = c("X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Z", "Z", "Z"),
    y = c("A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "A", "C", "D")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-8L))

> df
  x y
1 X A
2 X B
3 X C
4 Y B
5 Y C
6 Z A
7 Z C
8 Z D
```

and generate a list `u1` like below

```
u1 <- with(
  df,
  tapply(y, x, combn, 2, toString)
)
```

where

```
> u1
$X
[1] "A, B" "A, C" "B, C"

$Y
[1] "B, C"

$Z
[1] "A, C" "A, D" "C, D"

> str(u1)
List of 3
 $ X: chr [1:3(1d)] "A, B" "A, C" "B, C"
 $ Y: chr [1(1d)] "B, C"
 $ Z: chr [1:3(1d)] "A, C" "A, D" "C, D"
 - attr(*, "dim")= int 3
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "X" "Y" "Z"
```

When I ran `stack(u1)`, I will have the following error

```
> stack(u1)
Error in stack.default(u1) : at least one vector element is required
```

It seems that I cannot use `stack` over the output of `tapply` directly even if it is a named list.

However, when I use `u2 <- Map(c,u1)` for postprocessing, then things get working again

```
> u2 <- Map(c, u1)

> u2
$X
[1] "A, B" "A, C" "B, C"

$Y
[1] "B, C"

$Z
[1] "A, C" "A, D" "C, D"


> str(u2)
List of 3
 $ X: chr [1:3] "A, B" "A, C" "B, C"
 $ Y: chr "B, C"
 $ Z: chr [1:3] "A, C" "A, D" "C, D"

> stack(u2)
  values ind
1   A, B   X
2   A, C   X
3   B, C   X
4   B, C   Y
5   A, C   Z
6   A, D   Z
7   C, D   Z
```

As we can see, in `str(u2)`, the attributes are filtered out, which seems solving the issue.

---

## **My question is:**

Why `u1` failed but `u2` succeeded? Is there any other way I can use `tapply` over `u1` without any postprocessing (like `Map(c, u1)`)?

Answer (score 1):

`tapply` returns an `array` (or a `list` if you set `simplify = FALSE`), and `stack` doesn't like an array input. The `tapply` documentation doesn't sound like there are other output options. From `?tapply` (emphasis mine):

> `simplify`:
>
> `logical`; if `FALSE`, `tapply` always returns an array of mode "list"; in other words, a `list` with a `dim` attribute. If `TRUE` (the default), then if `FUN` always returns a scalar, **`tapply` returns an array** with the mode of the scalar.

So I'd recommend casting to character:

```
stack(lapply(u1, as.character))
#   values ind
# 1   A, B   X
# 2   A, C   X
# 3   B, C   X
# 4   B, C   Y
# 5   A, C   Z
# 6   A, D   Z
# 7   C, D   Z
```

If you're concerned about speed, you could run benchmarks to see, removing the `dim` attribute might be faster than `as.character()`,

```
stack(lapply(u1, "dim<-", NULL))
# same result
```

Answer (score 0):

Or may also use `as.vector/c` to remove the attributes and convert the `1d` vector to a vector with no dim attributes

```
stack(lapply(u1, c))
  values ind
1   A, B   X
2   A, C   X
3   B, C   X
4   B, C   Y
5   A, C   Z
6   A, D   Z
7   C, D   Z
```

According to `?stack`

> Note that stack applies to **vectors (as determined by is.vector)**: non-vector columns (e.g., factors) will be ignored with a warning.

The `is.vector` returns `FALSE` for all the member elements of 'u1'

```
> sapply(u1, is.vector)
    X     Y     Z 
FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

---

As @GregorThomas mentioned about the `simplify` argument in `tapply`, there is also a `simplify` option in `combn` which is TRUE by default.  If we specify that `FALSE`, it returns a `list` and should work

```
u1 <- with(
  df,
  tapply(y, x, FUN = function(u) combn(u, 2, FUN = toString, simplify = FALSE))
)
> stack(u1)
  values ind
1   A, B   X
2   A, C   X
3   B, C   X
4   B, C   Y
5   A, C   Z
6   A, D   Z
7   C, D   Z
```

---

However, this works with `enframe` on the `1d` vector as well

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
enframe(u1) %>%
   unnest(value)
# A tibble: 7 × 2
  name  value
  <chr> <chr>
1 X     A, B 
2 X     A, C 
3 X     B, C 
4 Y     B, C 
5 Z     A, C 
6 Z     A, D 
7 Z     C, D
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Upvoted! It seems some postprocessing of `u1` is inevitable before running `stack`. It is an interesting workaround using `enframe` + `unnest`

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding thanks.  or else as GregorThomas mentioned, the `tapply` output changed with `simplify`

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding I think the basic issue is also related to `combn` here.  i.e. `u1 <- with(
  df,
  tapply(y, x, FUN = function(u) combn(u, 2, FUN = toString, simplify = FALSE))
)` Now, you can use `stack(u1)`

Comment: Really nice finding in `combn`, super!